# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : YQL jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp, yql

I'm trying to get data from a JSON via Yahoo Query Language (YQL) using jQuery.

[Link to JSON](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.unisul.br%2Fwps%2Fportal%2Fhome%2Fconheca-a-unisul%2Fa-universidade%2Fcampus-unisul-virtual%2Fpolos-presenciais%27%20and%20xpath%3D%27%2F%2F%2a%5B%40id%3D%22lista-polos%22%5D%27&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=)

**index.html**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.unisul.br%2Fwps%2Fportal%2Fhome%2Fconheca-a-unisul%2Fa-universidade%2Fcampus-unisul-virtual%2Fpolos-presenciais'%20and%20xpath%3D'%2F%2F*%5B%40id%3D%22lista-polos%22%5D'&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (response) {

            var polos = response.results[0];
            var getPolosHTML = '';

            console.log(polos);

        }
    });
</script>
```

Error in console:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Any solution?

Comment: @Pogrindis Why? he isn't sending json to yql, he's receiving it FROM yql

Comment: You're right.. Well what is in the 'response' then ?

Comment: You're missing 1 character in your url. `callback=` should be `callback=?`. It will of course still fail though due to the format of the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to setup the url so that jquery will add in the jsonp param by adding a `?` to `callback=`

```
...&callback=?
```

then, you have to modify the success callback to properly reference the data.

```
var polos = response.query.results;
console.log(polos); // object with a div property
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jZ4n8/1/

Comment: Thanks! The reference to data had forgotten to change. But, `?` after callback was essential! Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

There is no error in code. Output of the api is invalid. You can cross check json result(http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: It is valid. Most likely when you copied the json, you didn't get all of it.